# Well-definedness of the logarithm in a Banach-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $x \in \mathcal{A}$ be an element of a unital Banach-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and assume $\sigma(x) \subset \{ z \in \mathbf{C} : \vert 1 - z \vert < 1 \}$, where $\sigma(x)$ denotes the spectrum of the operator $y \mapsto x y$.

Now define

$$ \log (x) := - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (1 - x)^n$$

I'd like to show that the right hand side converges.

My approach: I thought on showing that $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n} \Vert (1 - x)^n \Vert < + \infty$, which suffices as $\mathcal{A}$ is a Banach-space.

One thing to note would be that

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Vert (1 - x)^n \Vert^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma (x)} \vert 1 - \lambda \vert < 1$$

since $\sigma(1 - x) = \{ 1 - \lambda : \lambda \in \sigma(x) \}$.

However, I think this doesn't suffice. So I thought on showing that $\Vert (1 - x)^n \Vert = \Vert 1 - x \Vert^n$ as one does for normal operators to get that the spectral radius is equal to the norm. But I doubt that this works in the general setting of a Banach-algebra.

Could anyone help me on how to prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't suffice? (It does.)

Comment: Well, the only estimation I'd see here is that I can estimate $\sum_{n \geq n_0} \frac{1}{n} \Vert (1 - x)^n \Vert \leq \sum_{n \geq n_0} \frac{1}{n} (1 - \varepsilon)$ where $n_0$ is such that $\Vert (1 - x)^n \Vert < 1$ for all $n \geq n_0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough. But the RHS diverges...

Comment: No, there is a $c < 1$ such that for all large enough $n$ you have $\lVert (1-x)^n\rVert^{\frac{1}{n}} < c$. Then $\lVert (1-x)^n\rVert < c^n$.

Comment: Oh yes! Of course ... Thank you!